Python - check if empty response from GET request with HTTP lib
I have a simple basic question but I cannot find a reliable answer online nor in the lib's docs.
I have a sample code with does a GET request in Python, using lib http.client .
I want to check if the response body is empty or not before performing the json.loads(response) .
In the docs it's not explained how and the resources online I find use request or urllib, but I can only use http.client.
I tried considering checking the response length
if conn.getresponse().length < 1:
   print("Error: empty response")
else:
   json.loads(conn.getresponse().read().decode())

but I don't reckon it's reliable, so I'm considering something like
if conn.getresponse().read():
   json.loads(conn.getresponse().read().decode())
else:
   print("Error: empty response")

which I like more, but I'm not sure if it works: since the conn.getresponse().read returns an object in binary like
b'{\n  "field" : "0"}

my question here is if b'{} would be considered empty or not.
Thank you in advance.

From the http.client documentation, it says "[the http.client library] ... is normally not used directly — the module urllib.request uses it to handle URLs that use HTTP and HTTPS." Do you have a good reason to use the low-level library/package rather than the higher-level one? Kind regards. TL;DR why not use  urllib.request as recommended?

Hi @FlorianFasmeyer , I can see your point and I agree but the reason is simply the code is not mine (but from another team) and I would like to make less changes as possible

In the first example, it seems like it simply returns the raw resonse, for instance, an HTTP file starting with b'<!doctype html>\n<!--[if".... So you may need to define what an "empty body" is to you. You would expect a completely empty document, where body = b''. Given your description, I have a feeling your colleagues might have defined as empty body as a  dictionary with nothing but {"field" : "0"}.

@FlorianFasmeyer Yes, to me an empty body would be b'' . Actually the dictionary is the very response from the API call, no definition occured.

Question: "Is b'{}' considered empty or not?"
Answer: No

b'' is an empty sequence of bytes.
b'{}' is a sequence of two bytes, { and } respectively.

bool(b'') # False <=> Empty.
bool(b'{}') # True <=> Not Empty.

Read Bytes Literals.

However, an empty dictionary would be considered empty:
bool({}) # True <=> Empty.

And a Bytes Literal can be trivially turned into a string by decode-ing it.
b'{}'.decode() # Return '{}'

And you can turn a string of a dictionary into an actual Python dictionary by using the eval() function or read Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary for a safer(?) option.

Additionally, if it is not too fragile for your use-case, you may use the expression:
if response == b'{}': 
    ...


Oh-yes, when you have a json-like strucutre with dicts and lists, [value, ...] {key: value, ...} you can simply use json.dumps(var) ...
